# My MouseMotionListener is stopping my keyDown from working

Tags: java, applet, keydown, mousemotionlistener

Here is my code

```
Image duelSGX;
Image selectionBG;
Image Ultor;
Image serin;
int picWidth = 500;
int picHeight = 500;

int[] duelSGXStats = {4424, 1067, 2000};
int[] UltorStats = {4950, 2415, 1605};
int[] serinStats = {5993, 1647, 1527};

int appletsize_x = 300;
int appletsize_y = 200;

int x_pos = appletsize_x / 2;         // x - Position of ball
int y_pos = appletsize_y / 2;        // y - Position of ball

int radius = 20;        // Radius of ball

int x_coordinate = 500;
int y_coordinate;
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

boolean isButtonPressed = false;
public void init ()
{
    resize (1900, 960);
    selectionBG = getToolkit ().getImage (PICTURE_PATH1);
    duelSGX = getToolkit ().getImage (PICTURE_PATH);
    Ultor = getToolkit ().getImage (PICTURE_PATH2);
    serin = getToolkit ().getImage (PICTURE_PATH3);


    addMouseListener (this);
    addMouseMotionListener (this);


}


public void stop ()
{
}


public void destroy ()
{
}


public void run ()
{



}


public void update (Graphics g)
{

    // initialize buffer
    if (dbImage == null)
    {
        dbImage = createImage (this.getSize ().width, this.getSize ().height);
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();
    }

    // clear screen in background
    dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
    dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize ().width, this.getSize ().height);

    // draw elements in background
    dbg.setColor (getForeground ());
    paint (dbg);

    // draw image on the screen
    g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this);

}


public boolean keyDown (Event e, int key)
{
    Thread.currentThread ().setPriority (Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);


    if (key == Event.LEFT)
    {
        if (x_coordinate >= (-877 - 877))
        {
            x_coordinate -= 100;
        }

    }

    else if (key == Event.RIGHT)
    {
        if (x_coordinate <= 1900 - (677 + 200))
        {
            x_coordinate += 100;
        }
    }






    // DON'T FORGET (although it has no meaning here)
    repaint ();
    Thread.currentThread ().setPriority (Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    return true;

}


public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
{
    // called when the pointer enters the applet's rectangular area
}


public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
{
    // called when the pointer leaves the applet's rectangular area
}


public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
{
    // called after a press and release of a mouse button
    // with no motion in between
    // (If the user presses, drags, and then releases, there will be
    // no click event generated.)
}


public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
{
    ;
}


public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
{
}


public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e)
{
}


public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
{ // called during motion with buttons down

}


public void paint (Graphics g)
{

    g.drawImage (selectionBG, 0, 0, 1960, 960, null);

    g.drawImage (duelSGX, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, 677, 960, null);
    g.drawImage (Ultor, x_coordinate + 877, y_coordinate, 677, 960, null);
    g.drawImage (serin, x_coordinate + 877 + 877, y_coordinate, 677, 960, null);

}
```

The problem is that keyDown stops functioning when I add the mouseMotionlistener and the MouseListener in the init method. When I remove them it works.... What's going on here? Help Please?

Comment: When/where do you add the `KeyListener`?  `Applet` is like 15 years out of date, consider using a `JApplet` and Swing based component (like `JComponent` of `JPanel`), as you won't need to implement your own double buffering

Comment: I added the mouseListener in the init (). I didn't add keyListener, no idea where I would add that, and I don't know how to use those new applets......

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP isn't using `KeyListener` (although he/she should be) - the `keyDown` method of the `Component` class is being used.

Comment: From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) *"Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by processKeyEvent(KeyEvent)."* ...It might be better to do some investigation into `KeyListener` instead...

Comment: Ok I shall look into it...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the deprecated methods from the `Component` class. Use event listeners instead. You'll want to use `KeyListener` and `KeyEvent` in this case.

Add `KeyListener` at the top here.

```
public class SomeClass
    extends Applet
    implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
```

In your init method use the `Component` class's `addKeyListener` method.

```
public void init() {
    addKeyListener(this);
}
```

Then override the necessary methods (i.e. `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev)`).

In the `keyPressed` method, use the `KeyEvent` class's `getKeyCode` method and its fields to do what you need to do.

```
if (ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    // code here
}
```

This is pretty much the standard operation for handling input events such as key events and mouse events. As MadProgrammer mentioned above, it's a good idea to use Swing tools such as `JPanel` or `JApplet`, and to use key bindings with them.

Comment: And then use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)